# Javascript: calculate appended value

Tags: javascript

[image]

I have this table which adds service. Im trying to input evry quantity and display total on keyup on the right.

I can only get the first row working not the next rows.

Here are my codes

```
   $(document).on('keyup',function(){
   var pri = $('#price_display').val();
   var q = $('#qty_display').val();
   var tots = pri*q;

   $('#sub_display').val(tots);

   });
```

every row is added through append
**price_display** holds the price value
**qty_display** holds the inputted value
**sub_dispplay** holds the output value

Comment: Ids have to be **unique**

Comment: Use id for rows, but for columns use classes

Comment: Try using classes instead of ids? I believe you can only have one of each id.

Comment: if i use class. Every output is the same

Comment: For prevent it use id for rows

Comment: I tried that but it outputs the same value

Comment: You could take a Object Oriented js approach if you're familiar. Otherwise you could use an array for tots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm willing to bet each row has the same ID for each column (e.g. `id=price_display`).  IDs by definition need to be unique on each page, so jQuery always finds the first instance of each (i.e. the first row).

Probably the easiest way around this is to append a row number to each field, e.g. `price_display_1`, `qty_display_1`, `sub_quantity_1` etc. - that way jQuery can look for the right instance of each field.

See below for an example - although having said all this, it looks as though you're using something like Angular Material to style your page, so it might be worth your time investigating databinding in AngularJS to save you the hassle.

```js
// source data for table (array holds a JavaScript object per row)
var tableData = [{
    serviceCode: 'xbed',
    serviceName: 'xbed',
    price: 500,
    quantity: 1
  },
  {
    serviceCode: 'xpil',
    serviceName: 'xpil',
    price: 200,
    quantity: 2
  }
];

// find the table body
var $tableBody = $("#myTable").children("tbody");

// for each row of data, generate a table row 
tableData.forEach(function(row, index) {
  var rowIndex = index + 1;

  $tableBody.append("<tr>" +
    "<td><input type='text' id='service_code_" + rowIndex + "' value='" + row.serviceCode + "' /></td>" +
    "<td><input type='text' id='service_name_" + rowIndex + "' value='" + row.serviceName + "' /></td>" +
    "<td><input type='text' class='price' id='price_display_" + rowIndex + "' value='" + row.price + "' /></td>" +
    "<td><input type='text' class='qty' id='qty_display_" + rowIndex + "' value='" + row.quantity + "' /></td>" +
    "<td><input type='text' class='total' id='sub_display_" + rowIndex + "' value='" + row.price * row.quantity + "' /></td>" +
    "</tr>");
    
});

// wire up keyboard handlers
$(".price, .qty").on("keyup", function(evt) {
  var $row = $(evt.target).closest("tr"),
      price = $row.find(".price").first().val(),
      qty = $row.find(".qty").first().val(),
      $total = $row.find(".total").first();
  
  $total.val(price * qty);  
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

input {
  width: 8em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Service code</th>
      <th>Service name</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ive thought about that too but I'm thiking how to get those values

Answer (score 1):

Change ids to classes and try that code:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.qty_display, .price_display', function(){
   var row = $(this).parent('tr');
   var pri = row.find('.qty_display').val();
   var q = row.find('.price_display').val();
   var tots = pri*q;

   row.find('.sub_display').val(tots);
});
```

In that way you will change only need rows with correct values.

Comment: You should add the event handler on the closest possible parent element. `document` is way to high for this.

Comment: @Andreas I don't now which element is closest. Possibly it's table.

Comment: Doesnt display anything though

Comment: @PEENGEE Try to debug code. I don't have all your code or add markup in question

Answer (score 0):

try to log "tots" variable value, is it coming?

**if YES**

```
**THEN**

 make sure must have unique "#sub_display" id to display the value else it only appears on the first raw
```

**if NO**

```
**THEN**

  try to log the second raw object eg:-console.log(this)
```

Comment: im not familiar with logs but ill look into it. Thanks

Comment: i meant to console.log("value here ",variable)